# Searching for a good video converter for Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, video, conversion

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free video converter software for Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/82677/free-video-converter-software-for-mac)

Please recommend me a good tool for converting videos from avi to mpeg and so on.
(Host: OS X)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/82677/free-video-converter-software-for-mac

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/details.php) should be able to handle most of the common video formats.

Answer (score 1):

[AviDemux](http://fixounet.free.fr/avidemux/download.html), [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/downloads.php). These are the most common converters avaliable for free.
Also you can use simply [ffmpeg](http://www.haykranen.nl/2007/11/21/howto-install-and-use-ffmpeg-on-mac-os-x-leopard/) or [ffmpegX](http://homepage.mac.com/major4/) ([another howto](http://stephenjungels.com/jungels.net/articles/ffmpeg-howto.html)).
[Mencoder](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/design7/dload.html) is *also* avaliable.

(Mencoder and ffmpeg are both console based converters. It may take a few hours to get used to them but they can be really good/awesome and reliable. Once you get used to them... you can convert anything, anytime, from any OS. Also, people write frontends for them so you may have to search only (like ffmpegX). You can also write a batch script in terminal to make it convert all your files in a folder for example.)