# Any free mp4 convertors available for Mac OS X?

Tags: macos

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free video converter software for Mac?](https://superuser.com/questions/82677/free-video-converter-software-for-mac)

I have bought a new Nokia 5800. It supports only mp4 format files. I mainly have .avi files. Is there any free software available to convert to mp4 for Mac OS X?

Comment: Duplicates: http://superuser.com/questions/82677/free-video-converter-software-for-mac and http://superuser.com/questions/155628/searching-for-a-good-video-converter-for-mac-os-x

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/), it convert video to .mp4 and .mkv, it's easy to use and it's a free app also.
you can also use advance setting to convert with any kind of Quality you want.

Answer (score 0):

This [Videora Nokia converter](http://www.videora.com/en-us/Converter/nokia-5800-xpressmusic/) probably would be the easiest, as it's tailored to your advice. If you want more settings, I would go with Handbrake or WinFF.