# Are there any Mac OS X apps that convert Flash video (.flv) to h.264?

Tags: macos, mac, video, flv, h.264

I’ve got some video from the web in Flash video format (.flv). I want to convert it to h.264.

I’ve got Perian installed. QuickTime seems to play the video fine, but when I use any of the options to export it, I get audio, and a blank white screen instead of the video footage.

Are there any Mac OS X apps that convert FLV to h.264? (Command-line or GUI.)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Free video converter software for Mac?](http://superuser.com/questions/82677/free-video-converter-software-for-mac)

Comment: @Doug: definitely in the same ball park, but that question doesn’t mention Flash video, and mine doesn’t specify that the app has to be free.

Comment: I can't believe no one mentioned Evom on that thread, either. Dead-simple one-drop conversion to standard iPod format, and free.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [Evom](http://thelittleappfactory.com/evom/)?

Comment: I have not! But I shall.

Comment: What a great app, worked perfectly. Well played.

Comment: Care to elaborate on what's so awesome about Evom @ghoppe?

Comment: Evom is free, made by "little app factory" (a well known mac developer), and it works fantastic!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with ffmpeg and no transcoding if the FLV contains an already H264 encoded video (quite common). Here's how I got it (assuming you have git and Xcode installed, e.g. that you can compile)

```
git clone git://source.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.git ffmpeg
cd ffmpeg
./configure --enable-shared --disable-mmx --arch=x86_64
make
make install
ffmpeg -i "file.flv" -vcodec copy -acodec copy file.mkv
```

Optionally, you can convert the file.mkv to MP4 in [Subler](http://code.google.com/p/subler/)

Answer (score 1):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org) doesn't just play anything, it can also reencode things.
If you need batch conversion with a GUI, you could do worse than AppGeeker ([flv to mp4 h.264 mac](http://www.ilikemall.com/how-to/convert-flv-to-mp4-mac.html)). 
If you want batch conversion, and insanely precise control at the expense of an insanely obtuse command line interface, [ffmpeg](http://www.ffmpeg.org) is the best thing ever.

Answer (score 0):

HandBrake would be a better option, and is much faster than Evom for me.